# WebClient Authentication on HTTPS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https

I am using the WebClient class to write a program that downloads all files on an HTTP server. I am having issues trying to authenticate via WebClient's Credentials property. When I navigate to this site in a browser (image shown is firefox), it asks for authentication in the following way:
[image]

Here's how I'm attempting to gain access to this server:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://url-is-here.org/ftp/some-more-stuff");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username-here", "password-here");
request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;    //Not sure if these
request.PreAuthenticate = true;           //two lines are needed
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

However, I get an exception when calling `GetResponse()` saying:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or 
decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or
decryption has failed.
```

Part of what's confusing me is that although the site calls itself an ftp site (it actually says that in the real URL like in the dummy URL above), the URL begins with https rather than ftp. I was originally using a `FtpWebRequest` instead of a `WebRequest` but then I'd just get this exception when trying to create the `FtpWebRequest` object by casting the result of `WebRequest.Create()`:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
```

Any ideas? I'm new to this type of work, so both fixes and new insights would be greatly appreciated...